# How to force XSLT to escape chars to numerical format (&#160;) instead of name format (&nbsp;)?

Tags: xslt, character-encoding, docbook

I am using Docbook-XSL to process an XML file and produce HTML and XML output files. These files will be used for the online-help in an Eclipse RCP application.

The standard XSL does not produce a contexts.xml file needed to enable F1 context help so I have made use of an XSL I found online here http://blogs.itemis.de/leipzig/archives/691.

This works fine until I add German umlauts into the source text. These characters get converted into named entities such as &auml; and &szlig;. This causes errors in the outputted XML as these entities cannot be found.

Is there a way to tell the XSL processor to used the numbered entities such as &#223;?

(I could perform a search and replace on the output file but this seems a bit clumsy...)

The top-level XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:ng="http://docbook.org/docbook-ng" xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
        xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0"
        exclude-result-prefixes="exsl db ng">

        <!-- make sure the path to the standard eclipse.xsl is correct -->
        <xsl:import href="docbook-xsl-1.78.1/eclipse/eclipse3.xsl" />


        <xsl:param name="manifest">
            1
        </xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="create.plugin.xml">
            1
        </xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="create.context.xml">
            1
        </xsl:param>
        <xsl:param name="context.constants.package">
            org.example.help
        </xsl:param>

        <xsl:template name="plugin.xml">
            <xsl:if test="$create.context.xml = '1'">
                <xsl:call-template name="context.xml" />
                <xsl:call-template name="contextconstants">
                    <xsl:with-param name="package">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$context.constants.package" />
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="$create.plugin.xml = '1'">
                <xsl:call-template name="write.chunk">
                    <xsl:with-param name="filename">
                        <xsl:if test="$manifest.in.base.dir != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$base.dir" />
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'plugin.xml'" />
                    </xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="method" select="'xml'" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="encoding" select="'utf-8'" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="'yes'" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="content">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$manifest = '1'">
                                <plugin>
                                    <extension point="org.eclipse.help.toc">
                                        <toc file="toc.xml" primary="true" />
                                    </extension>
                                    <extension point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
                                        <contexts file="contexts.xml"></contexts>
                                    </extension>
                                </plugin>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <plugin name="{$eclipse.plugin.name}" id="{$eclipse.plugin.id}"
                                    version="1.0" provider-name="{$eclipse.plugin.provider}">
                                    <extension point="org.eclipse.help.toc">
                                        <toc file="toc.xml" primary="true" />
                                    </extension>
                                </plugin>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template name="context.xml">
            <xsl:call-template name="write.chunk">
                <xsl:with-param name="filename" select="'contexts.xml'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="method" select="'xml'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="encoding" select="'utf-8'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="'yes'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="quiet" select="$chunk.quietly" />
                <xsl:with-param name="content">
                    <contexts>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="context.xml" />
                    </contexts>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template
            match="book|part|reference|preface|chapter|bibliography|appendix|article|glossary|section|sect1|sect2|sect3|sect4|sect5|refentry|colophon|bibliodiv|index"
            mode="context.xml">
            <xsl:variable name="title">
                <xsl:if test="$eclipse.autolabel=1">
                    <xsl:variable name="label.markup">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="label.markup" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($label.markup)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($label.markup,$autotoc.label.separator)" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="title.markup" />
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:variable name="href">
                <xsl:call-template name="href.target.with.base.dir">
                    <xsl:with-param name="context" select="/" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>

            <!-- <xsl:message>Node=<xsl:value-of select="name(.)"></xsl:value-of>, 
                ID=<xsl:call-template name="object.id"> <xsl:with-param name="object" select="."/> 
                </xsl:call-template></xsl:message> -->

            <xsl:call-template name="acontext">
                <xsl:with-param name="id">
                    <xsl:call-template name="object.id">
                        <xsl:with-param name="object" select="." />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="label" select="$title" />
                <xsl:with-param name="href" select="$href" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="part|reference|preface|chapter|bibliography|appendix|article|glossary|section|sect1|sect2|sect3|sect4|sect5|refentry|colophon|bibliodiv|index"
                mode="context.xml" />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="acontext">
            <xsl:param name="id" />
            <xsl:param name="label" />
            <xsl:param name="href" />
            <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$id"/>, <xsl:value-of select="$href"/>
            </xsl:message>
            <context id="{normalize-space($id)}" title="">
                <description />
                <topic href="{$href}" label="{normalize-space($label)}" />
            </context>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template name="contextconstants">
            <xsl:param name="package" />
            <xsl:call-template name="write.chunk">
                <xsl:with-param name="filename" select="'ContextConstants.java'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="method" select="'java'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="encoding" select="'utf-8'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="'yes'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="quiet" select="$chunk.quietly" />
                <xsl:with-param name="content">
                    package
                    <xsl:value-of select="$package" />
                    ;
                    public class ContextConstants{
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="contextconstants" />
                    }
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template
            match="book|part|reference|preface|chapter|bibliography|appendix|article|glossary|section|sect1|sect2|sect3|sect4|sect5|refentry|colophon|bibliodiv|index"
            mode="contextconstants">
            <xsl:variable name="title">
                <xsl:if test="$eclipse.autolabel=1">
                    <xsl:variable name="label.markup">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="label.markup" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($label.markup)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($label.markup,$autotoc.label.separator)" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="title.markup" />
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:variable name="href">
                <xsl:call-template name="href.target.with.base.dir">
                    <xsl:with-param name="context" select="/" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:call-template name="acontextconstant">
                <xsl:with-param name="id">
                    <xsl:call-template name="object.id">
                        <xsl:with-param name="object" select="." />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="label" select="$title" />
                <xsl:with-param name="href" select="$href" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="part|reference|preface|chapter|bibliography|appendix|article|glossary|section|sect1|sect2|sect3|sect4|sect5|refentry|colophon|bibliodiv|index"
                mode="contextconstants" />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="acontextconstant">
            <xsl:param name="id" />
            <xsl:param name="label" />
            <xsl:param name="href" />
            public static final String C_
            <xsl:value-of select="translate($id,'-','_')" />
            ="
            <xsl:value-of select="$id" />
            ";
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "an XSL I found online" - can you provide a link, and edit the question to include the relevant parts of this stylesheet? We can't debug the code if we don't know what it looks like.

Comment: It sounds to me like the XSLT is configured to produce HTML rather than XML output, can you show the `<xsl:output>` declaration?

Comment: @IanRoberts - done. The XSL is added on top of the DOCBOOK XSLs. The standard produces a number of HTML files, a MANIFEST.MF and toc.xml. This XSL creates a contexts.xml as well.

Comment: If you want to create an XML result document but get HTML entity references in the output then it sounds as if the `xsl:output method="xml"` is not set and is set instead as `xsl:output method="html"`. The output method `html` is also used by the XSLT processor if `xsl:output` does not set one and the root element of the result tree is `html` in no namespace. So make sure you have `<xsl:output method="xml"/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - tried that but then the HTML files do not have their meta encoding set at all

Comment: Are you creating multiple files with a single stylesheet? If you do that but the different files need different output method types then you need to make sure you put the output method at the right place, like http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html in XSLT 1.0 with the EXSLT extension (`<exsl:document href="contexts.xml" method "xml">...</exsl:document>`) respectively the same for XSLT 2.0 and `xsl:result-document`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen this is what the `<xsl:with-param name="method" select="'xml'" />` passed to `write.chunk` _should_ do but it uses processor-specific extensions - if you're using a processor that supports `exsl:document` or `saxon:output` it should work, but Xalan with `redirect:write` doesn't support different methods for different output files.

Comment: @IanRoberts, I see, then the only option is to use an XSLT processor that supports using different methods for different output files or to use different stylesheets for each type of output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Saxon then you could try saxon:character-representation: see

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensions/output-extras/character-representation

Needs Saxon-PE or higher.

However, I'm confused about your requirements. If you want XML output, use method="xml". In that case you won't get a  tag generated. If you want a  tag but don't want HTML character references, you seem to want some kind of hybrid, and I'm not sure why. Perhaps method="xhtml" will fit your needs?